# C struct with switch case, input line skipping

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

So I have decided to go with a switch case that I've used in a past program. It works as intended except for the first line of each case, the input account name skips it's input line. I am sure it's something simple and I've been at it for while now. Below is the code, just trying to get the line to allow input other than that it saves to the file and continues to save input when prompted to continue through my cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct account 
{
char company_name[256];
int invoice_number;
int invoice_date;
float invoice_amount;

};


int main() 
{
char *end;
char buf[256];
char y;
char n;
char a;
FILE *newacct;
struct account ledger;
newacct = fopen("robco.txt", "a");



printf("Enter Account Name:");
fgets(ledger.company_name, sizeof(ledger.company_name), stdin);
ledger.company_name[strlen(ledger.company_name)-1] = '\0';
printf("Enter Incoive Number:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_number = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
printf("Enter Invoice Date:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_date = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
printf("Enter Invoice Amount:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_amount = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
fprintf(newacct,"%s %d %d %f\n", ledger.company_name, ledger.invoice_number, 
ledger.invoice_date, ledger.invoice_amount);
fclose(newacct);



printf("Would you like to enter more data?:");
scanf("%s", &a);


switch (a){

case'n':

printf("Thanks for your entry!"); //should terminate
fprintf(newacct,"\n%s %d %d %f", ledger.company_name, ledger.invoice_number, 
ledger.invoice_date, ledger.invoice_amount);
fclose(newacct);

return 0;

case'y':    
FILE *newacct;
struct account ledger;
newacct = fopen("robco.txt", "a");

printf("Enter Account Name:"); //the line that keeps skipping in every switch 
case.
fgets(ledger.company_name, sizeof(ledger.company_name), stdin); //it prints 
however it skips this input line.
ledger.company_name[strlen(ledger.company_name)-1] = '\0';
printf("\nEnter Incoive Number:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_number = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
printf("Enter Invoice Date:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_date = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
printf("Enter Invoice Amount:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_amount = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
fprintf(newacct,"%s %d %d %f\n", ledger.company_name, ledger.invoice_number, 
ledger.invoice_date, ledger.invoice_amount);
fclose(newacct);

break;
}
printf("Would you like to enter more data?:");
scanf("%s", &a);


switch (a){

case'n':

printf("Thanks for your entry!"); //should terminate
fprintf(newacct,"\n%s %d %d %f", ledger.company_name, ledger.invoice_number, 
ledger.invoice_date, ledger.invoice_amount);
fclose(newacct);

return 0;

case'y':
FILE *newacct;
struct account ledger;
newacct = fopen("robco.txt", "a");

printf("Enter Account Name:");
fgets(ledger.company_name, sizeof(&ledger.company_name), stdin);
ledger.company_name[strlen(ledger.company_name)-1] = '\0';
printf("Enter Incoive Number:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_number = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
printf("Enter Invoice Date:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_date = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
printf("Enter Invoice Amount:");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
ledger.invoice_amount = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
fprintf(newacct,"%s %d %d %f\n", ledger.company_name, ledger.invoice_number, 
ledger.invoice_date, ledger.invoice_amount);
fclose(newacct);

break;
}
}
```

Comment: so get rid of the q and insert newacct

Comment: Please make your source code readable: 1) bring it in good form in your editor,   2) copy it and paste it in StackOverfow "Add Question" edit box,   3) Select the code   4) Press Ctrl+K   5) Feel happy.

Comment: Please, indent your code properly so it's readable. Also, Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. Another thing you can try is to test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you.

Comment: See http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/ for more info about how to improve your question.

Comment: thanks my debugger on Dev C isn't cooperating it shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to get you going. Note that I [avoided using](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct account {
    int account_number;
    char last_name[32];
};

int main(void) {
    char buf[256];
    char *end;
    FILE *newacct;
    struct account ledger;
    newacct = fopen("robco.txt", "a");

    // collect last name from stdin
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    fgets(ledger.last_name, sizeof(ledger.last_name), stdin);
    ledger.last_name[strlen(ledger.last_name)-1] = '\0';

    // collect account number from stdin
    printf("Enter account number: ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    ledger.account_number = strtol(buf, &end, 10);

    // write to file
    fprintf(newacct, "%s %d\n", ledger.last_name, ledger.account_number);
    fclose(newacct);

    // read and print contents of file
    newacct = fopen("robco.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(newacct, "%s %d", ledger.last_name, &ledger.account_number) != EOF) {
        printf("%s %d\n", ledger.last_name, ledger.account_number);
    }

    fclose(newacct);
    return 0;
}
```

A few brief remarks about your code:

- `fscanf` and `feof` should take the file pointer as the first argument.
- Pass references to integers into `fscanf` rather than integers themselves.
- Your struct has a pointer to a `char`, but at no point is the size determined and memory allocated--you can either `malloc` this dynamically at runtime or pre-allocate it at compile time as above.

Comment: Thanks I had tried yours, it does function well. I took out the read from acct. However I inserted a switch case I'd like to have the program allow user input until the user terminates or it goes up to 8-10 inputs. Just new to all this and trying some stuff to quickly.